# Remove () from a string using re library in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I remove the following `(<span class=saws></span>)` from the string below

```
<p>In the house of Um-Salama I saw Allah's Messenger (<span class=saws></span>) offering prayers, wrapped in a single garment 
around his body with its ends crossed round his shoulders.</b></div>
```

I have tried everything, i managed to remove `<span class=saws></span>`, but i cannot get rid of `()` now

Code:

```
url = "http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/8"

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
html   = etree.parse(url, parser)
result = etree.tostring(html.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method="html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(result) 

results = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "actualHadithContainer"})
for result in results :

    en = re.sub('</span>|<div class="text_details">|</div>|</p>|<p>|<span class=|[??]|("saws">)','',str(result.find("div", {"class" : "text_details"})))
    en1 = re.sub('()','',str(en))
    print en1
    ar1 = re.sub('<span class="arabic_sanad arabic">|</span>','',str(result.find("span", {"class" : "arabic_sanad arabic"})))
    ar2 = re.sub('<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">|</span>|<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">','',str(result.find("span", {"class" : "arabic_text_details arabic"})))
    print ar1 + ar2
```

Comment: Can't you just `htmlSource.replace("(<span class=saws></span>)", "")`?

Comment: Change your regexp to `\(old_regexp\)` (enclose it in escaped parenthesis)

Comment: how can i do this using lxml, tim

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple like

`(\(<span\sclass\=saws\>.*</span>\))`

This will remove the whole `(<span class=saws></span>)`

See http://regex101.com/r/uL3fV4 for a live demo

Comment: Nice link, my answer using re.sub('</span>|<div class="text_details">|</div>|</p>|<p>|[??]|\(<span class="saws"></span>\)|<b>|</b>','',str(result.find("div", {"class" : "text_details"})))  i pretty short as I use it to remove other expressions, I was missing \ in front of the ( & )

Answer (score 0):

My example with BeatufulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(u"""<p>In the house of Um-Salama I saw Allah's 
Messenger (<span class=saws></span>) offering prayers, wrapped in a single garment 
around his body with its ends crossed round his shoulders.</b></div>""")
results = soup.findAll()
for tag in results:
    if tag.name == 'span' and 'saws' in tag.attrs.get('class', []):
        tag.extract()

print re.sub(ur'\(\)', u'', unicode(soup))
```

Comment: my code "check my edit" also extracts other tag in a loop, so your answer above is not helpfull :(

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                 
import urllib2 
import lxml    
from lxml import etree                                                                                                                                           
import re

url = "http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/8"

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
html   = etree.parse(url, parser)
result = etree.tostring(html.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method="html")
# content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(result) 

results = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "actualHadithContainer"})
for result in results :

    en = re.sub('</span>|<div class="text_details">|</div>|</p>|<p>|[??]|\(<span class="saws"></span>\)|<b>|</b>','',str(result.find("div", {"class" : "text_details"})))
    print en

    ar1 = re.sub('<span class="arabic_sanad arabic">|</span>','',str(result.find("span", {"class" : "arabic_sanad arabic"})))
    ar2 = re.sub('<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">|</span>|<span class="arabic_text_details arabic">','',str(result.find("span", {"class" : "arabic_text_details arabic"})))
    print ar1 + ar2
```